# how to run the batch file from any folder

Tags: java, batch-file

```
cd ../../jobs
set CLASSPATH=.;../xyz.jar;../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
java folser.folder1 ../Files/MySQL.xml
cd ..
```

I need to run the batch file from any directory.  I have set the paths for java.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is this Windows or Linux? Your use of "/" in the cd command indicates Linux but you talk about batch files rather than shell scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Under *nix (e.g. Linux):

```
cd "`dirname \"$0\"`"
# your current directoy is now the script's directory
cd ../../jobs
set CLASSPATH=.:../xyz.jar:../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
java folder.folder1 ../Files/MySQL.xml
cd ..
# when the script terminates, you are automatically
#  back to the original directory
```

Under Windows NT/XP/etc.:

```
SETLOCAL
PUSHD .
REM current directory has been saved and environment is protected
CD /d %~dp0
REM your current directoy is now the script's directory
CD ..\..\jobs
SET CLASSPATH=.;..\xyz.jar;..\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
java folder.folder1 ..\Files\MySQL.xml
CD ..
REM before the script terminates, you must explicitly
REM return back to the original directory
POPD
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I don't think you're back in the original directory at the end for the Windows version. You should use setlocal/endlocal to ensure environment changes don't leak out of the script - you may also need to store the current path and drive and restore when finished.

Comment: And +1. Well, stuff me! I didn't even know about pushd/popd, I've been saving my PWD in an environment variable. Must remember to change that code next time it's checked out.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't comment on Vlad's answer (comments require more points than answers?!) I would always be wary of relying on:

```
CD /d %~dp0
```

because Windows can't CD to UNC paths and has a nasty habit of dropping you into %windir% instead with potentially catastrophic results.

Instead, although it is more long-winded, you are usually better off referring to %~dp0 (or a variable containing that value) each time you need a full path.

BAD:

```
cd /d %~dp0
rd temp
```

GOOD:

```
rd %~dp0\temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You message was a bit garbled, I'm assuming you're saying that java is on the path but you can't properly run your application from a batch file.  It looks like you are missing the classpath option (-cp) for java.  Try this:

> ```
> cd ../../jobs
> set CLASSPATH=.;../xyz.jar;../mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar
> java -cp %CLASSPATH% folser.folder1 ../Files/MySQL.xml
> cd ..
> ```

Comment: This does not answer the poster's question

Comment: Do you need "-cp"? I though Java picked it up automagically from CLASSPATH (although you may need to export rather than just set).

Answer (score 0):

Use %cd% to get the current directory (i.e. the one that the batch file lives in)

e.g.

```
set JAVA_HOME=%cd%\jdk1.x.x
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%cd%\lib\myjar.jar;etc,etc
```

Comment: %cd% is not the batch file's directory, it is the current directory, e.g. I'm in C:\, I invoke C:\test\batch.bat; %cd% is C:\, not C:\test.

Comment: @Richard - %~dp0 would get the batch file directory